# thymleaf map within a map value (nested map)

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Given the following structure:

```
Map<String, String> image = new HashMap<>();
image.put("thumbnail", "1.png");
image.put("medium", "2.png");
image.put("large", "3.png");

Map<Long, Map<String, String>> imageMap = new HashMap<>();
imageMap.put(1L, image);
```

In the front-end how can one obtain the image for: 1 > thumbnail

`<image th:src="${imageMap[__${myObjct.id}__]}" height="10px" width="10px"/>`

The above should return a map with key values pairs. What I would like is the value for the key 'thumbnail'.

I would have thought this would work:
`${imageMap['1']['thumbnail']}`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the asterisk `*` notation here:

> the asterisk syntax evaluates expressions on selected objects rather
>   than on the whole context variables map

So `*{imageMap['1']['thumbnail']}` should work. Try it!

Comment: Oh error ! EL1012E:(pos 13): Cannot index into a null value. hmm
While no error for `*{imageMap['1']}`

Comment: Funnily enough changing the `imageMap` key from **Long** to **String** seems to work.

Comment: Ah yes, that does make it easier to parse using thymeleaf ;) Well done! You solved it yourself. The null pointer is because there is no `imageMap['1']` apparently